# Pandas conditions across multiple series

Tags: python, pandas, series

Lets say I have some data like this:

```
category = pd.Series(np.ones(4))

job1_days = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2])
job1_time = pd.Series([30, 35, 50, 10])

job2_days = pd.Series([1, 3, 1, 3])
job2_time = pd.Series([10, 40, 60, 10])

job3_days = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 3])
job3_time = pd.Series([30, 15, 50, 15])
```

Each entry represents an individual (so 4 people total). `xxx_days` represents the number of days an individual did something and `xxx_time` represents the number of minutes spent doing that job on a single day

I want to assign a `2` to `category` for an individual, if *across all jobs* they spent at least 3 days of 20 minutes each. So for example, person 1 does not meet the criteria because they only spent 2 total days with at least 20 minutes (their job 2 day count does not count toward the total because time is < 20). Person 2 does meet the criteria as they spent 5 total days (jobs 1 and 2).

After replacement, `category` should look like this:
`[1, 2, 2, 1]`

My current attempt to do this requires a for loop and manually indexing into each series and calculating the total days where time is greater than 20. However, this approach doesn't scale well to my actual dataset. I haven't included the code here as i'd like to approach it from a Pandas perspective instead

Whats the most efficient way to do this in Pandas? The thing that stumps me is checking conditions across multiple series and act accordingly after summation of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put *days* and *time* in two data frames with column positions correspondence maintained, then do the calculation in a vectorized approach:

```
import pandas as pd

time = pd.concat([job1_time, job2_time, job3_time], axis = 1)   ​
days = pd.concat([job1_days, job2_days, job3_days], axis = 1)

((days * (time >= 20)).sum(1) >= 3) + 1

#0    1
#1    2
#2    2
#3    1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error: `unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects`. I've made sure that the `dtype` is float. I wonder if its because there are `NA` (missing) values? Is there a way to account for that?

Comment: It seems you have string in your series data. You might want to try this. `((days.astype(float) * (time.astype(float) >= 20)).sum(1) >= 3) + 1`, not sure if it solves the problem though.

Comment: Yep Ive tried that but still doesn't work. `time.dtypes` and `day.dtypes` both report `float64` as well. The problem seems to come from this part: `(day * (time >= 20))`. `time >= 20` creates a dataframe of `bool` types, but when I multiply it by `day` the returning dataframe contains all `NaN`. I think the problem is trying to use `NaN` (string) in the comparison. Is there another way to do that masking without `*`?

Comment: That's weird, because `float * bool` should give `float` but you can try to convert them to numpy array. `((days.values * (time.values >= 20)).sum(1) >= 3) + 1`, and see if it works. Or `((days.values.astype(float) * (time.values.astype(float) >= 20)).sum(1) >= 3) + 1`